# repeating x axis values in ggplot and geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't like to use Excel to produce my plots so I want to use R instead and `ggplot2` if possible.
This is my dataset and probably it is not in the right format for doing what I want to do:

```
    C>A         C>G         C>T         T>A         T>C         T>G
ACA 0.049915398 0.008460237 0.018612521 0.015228426 0.036379019 0.005922166
ACC 0.015228426 0.003384095 0.010152284 0.005922166 0.005076142 0
ACG 0.014382403 0.005076142 0.010998308 0.007614213 0.013536379 0.001692047
ACT 0.031302876 0.007614213 0.01607445  0.010998308 0.013536379 0.002538071
CCA 0.021150592 0.005076142 0.011844332 0.007614213 0.011844332 0.001692047
CCC 0.027072758 0.002538071 0.009306261 0.005076142 0.004230118 0
CCG 0.014382403 0.001692047 0.009306261 0.005076142 0.008460237 0.000846024
CCT 0.0321489   0.00676819  0.016920474 0.00676819  0.008460237 0.000846024
GCA 0.011844332 0.003384095 0.015228426 0.003384095 0.013536379 0.002538071
GCC 0.008460237 0.004230118 0.010152284 0.007614213 0.011844332 0.003384095
GCG 0.002538071 0.004230118 0.010998308 0.009306261 0.010998308 0.003384095
GCT 0.012690355 0.005076142 0.010998308 0.003384095 0.005076142 0.000846024
TCA 0.030456853 0.011844332 0.013536379 0.011844332 0.017766497 0.001692047
TCC 0.026226734 0.00676819  0.017766497 0.002538071 0.004230118 0.002538071
TCG 0.011844332 0.000846024 0.009306261 0.003384095 0.011844332 0.000846024
TCT 0.03891709  0.016920474 0.020304569 0.008460237 0.019458545 0.00676819
```

From this dataset I would like to produce something like this:
[image: The values on the X axis are repeated for each column]

Can you help me? Everything I produce is far from what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are certainly looking for this result - I use `tidyr` or `reshape2` library to shape the data first:

```
library(reshape2)

df1 = melt(df, id.vars='Gene', variable.name='Class', value.name='Value')
#df1 = gather(df, Class, Value, -Gene) using tidyr

df1 = transform(df1, x=1:nrow(df1))

ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=Value, fill=Class)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels=df1$Gene) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

**Data:**

```
df = structure(list(Gene = c("ACA", "ACC", "ACG", "ACT", "CCA", "CCC", 
"CCG", "CCT", "GCA", "GCC", "GCG", "GCT", "TCA", "TCC", "TCG", 
"TCT"), C.A = c(0.049915398, 0.015228426, 0.014382403, 0.031302876, 
0.021150592, 0.027072758, 0.014382403, 0.0321489, 0.011844332, 
0.008460237, 0.002538071, 0.012690355, 0.030456853, 0.026226734, 
0.011844332, 0.03891709), C.G = c(0.008460237, 0.003384095, 0.005076142, 
0.007614213, 0.005076142, 0.002538071, 0.001692047, 0.00676819, 
0.003384095, 0.004230118, 0.004230118, 0.005076142, 0.011844332, 
0.00676819, 0.000846024, 0.016920474), C.T = c(0.018612521, 0.010152284, 
0.010998308, 0.01607445, 0.011844332, 0.009306261, 0.009306261, 
0.016920474, 0.015228426, 0.010152284, 0.010998308, 0.010998308, 
0.013536379, 0.017766497, 0.009306261, 0.020304569), T.A = c(0.015228426, 
0.005922166, 0.007614213, 0.010998308, 0.007614213, 0.005076142, 
0.005076142, 0.00676819, 0.003384095, 0.007614213, 0.009306261, 
0.003384095, 0.011844332, 0.002538071, 0.003384095, 0.008460237
), T.C = c(0.036379019, 0.005076142, 0.013536379, 0.013536379, 
0.011844332, 0.004230118, 0.008460237, 0.008460237, 0.013536379, 
0.011844332, 0.010998308, 0.005076142, 0.017766497, 0.004230118, 
0.011844332, 0.019458545), T.G = c(0.005922166, 0, 0.001692047, 
0.002538071, 0.001692047, 0, 0.000846024, 0.000846024, 0.002538071, 
0.003384095, 0.003384095, 0.000846024, 0.001692047, 0.002538071, 
0.000846024, 0.00676819)), .Names = c("Gene", "C.A", "C.G", "C.T", 
"T.A", "T.C", "T.G"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't use `tidyr`. Is there a way to do the same thing using `reshape2`?

Comment: Yes, I edited my code so that you can use `reshape2`. Just have in mind `going wide to long` -> use `melt`, `going long to wide data` -> use `dcast`

Comment: Did you created the dataframe like that or is it the result of the `melt`? beacuse I don't get the same plot as you do. I got a stacked chart instead.

Comment: Do you have problem to read something ? ;) I use `df` as defined in data since you did not give any `dput` of your data. I refactored the code so that it becomes clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this, where df is your dataframe:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

df$rowvalues <- rownames(df)
gather(df, Variables, Values, 2:ncol(df)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = rowvalues, y = Values, fill = Variables) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Version 2 without using magrittrs pipe-operator and using reshape2 instead of tidyr:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df$rowvalues <- rownames(df)
df.long <- melt(df, id.vars = ("rowvalues"),
 variable.name = "variable_name", 
 value.name = "value_name")
ggplot(df.long, aes(x = rowvalues, y = value_name, fill = variable_name) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: They are rowids, repeated each time for each column.

Comment: then the above answer should get you what you want, please update your original post to make this clear, have you tried the solution yet?

Comment: I am trying but `tidyr` package is not available for my version of R (3.0.2).

Comment: i changed my solution using reshape 2 instead, try that

Comment: does it work? if so please accept the solution by clicking the tick

Comment: We are getting closer, it is definitely the right direction. In the Excel plot, however, `rowvalues` are repeated every time for each `variable_name`.